# referring to log4j configuration file from a log4j configuration file on class path

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, log4j

I have a common jar that multiple web applications are using. All the web applications are using log4j. Each has their own log4j xml configuration file that are basically the same. I would like to put a common log4j configuration in the included jar file and in each individual web project, in that log4j configuration, I would like to be able to simply refer to the one in the jar file.

I'm not seeing anything in the documentation that explicitly says this is possible. I'm wondering if I might just remove the configuration file from the web projects and stick it in the common jar if it would get loaded automatically since it is on the class path?

In the end, I would like the ability to adjust logging on a particular application for debugging and troubleshooting without modifying the common configuration in the jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on a project where I needed to manage dozens of web applications. Each of the apps were logging slightly differently and it was a pretty big pain to manage. I used a strategy similar to what you are describing to standardize on log4j and it has worked out pretty well.

Basically, I created a single common.jar which contains shared code. This jar contains a log4j.xml that sets log level to INFO and sets the default appender to stdout for common.jar. This log4j config is used as the baseline for all other apps.

For this example, pretend this class is inside common.jar:

```
public class ThirdPartyLib 
{
    protected static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("third-party-lib");
    public void doSomething()
    {
        log.debug("Third Party App is about to Do something!");
        log.info("Third Party App just did something");
    }
}
```

Now, all other web applications can simply depend on common.jar. For example, pretend this class is inside myapp.war:

```
public class MyApp
{
    public void CallThirdParty()
    {
        ThirdPartyLib lib = new ThirdPartyLib();
        lib.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Since log4j.xml is inside common.jar, this code will log something like this. In other words, there's no need to put log4j.xml inside myapp.war:

```
2011-01-03 15:49:22,451 [main] INFO  third-party-lib - Third Party App just did something
```

Now, if you want/need to control logging in myapp.war, then simply place a log4j.xml inside myapp.war and override settings from common.jar. For example, you might set the level to DEBUG, and then you'll see:

```
2011-01-03 16:03:22,928 [main] DEBUG third-party-lib - Third Party App is about to Do something!
2011-01-03 16:03:22,928 [main] INFO  third-party-lib - Third Party App just did something
```

**UPDATE - Is it possible to configure each webapp to log to separate file?**

Yes, definitely. For example, you can direct logs to a RollingFileAppender instead of stdout inside log4j.xml for myapp.war. This is handy because then you can have each individual webapp log to it's own separate file.

In addition, I wrote a servlet filter (similar to what gigadot suggested) which configures log4j to check for whether a log4j.xml exists at an external path (outside of each webapp's war). This way, the log4j.xml files are accessible outside the wars and we're able to set log levels without restarting the servlet container (tomcat, in this case). If the external log4j.xml doesn't exist, it defaults to use the log4j.xml on each apps classpath.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking, however, to further complicate matters, each web app has an appender that logs to a different file based on the webapp. If I reduce my individual project configurations down to just this information, will it override or replace the configuration from the ThirdPartyLib?

Comment: Hey Casey, any configs inside log4j.xml in each individual app will override the stuff inside log4j.xml inside the common.jar. So, adding a file appender in each app's log4j.xml should work well. I updated my response with more info. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, also the note about storing them outside the wars I find interesting as I have run into this problem, needing to debug something in production but not wanting to leave the log level to debug etc. Being able to have someone on our prod team update a single file would be great.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure that can help but you can set property file location like this,

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=jar:file:/full/path/to/app.jar!/log4j.properties -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not really going to help me here. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple jar/war files, each file have its own log4j.xml and you don't want to worry about which log4j.xml get loaded, you can explicitly load the configuration yourself.

For a webapp project, put the following context listener as the first listener in your web.xml This will load log4j from your path of preferrence.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>mycompany.server.listener.Log4JInitServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Implementation of `Log4JInitServletContextListener`.

Note: if you have multiple log4j.xml in the same path (which is possible for multiple jar files), it will be confusing which one gets loaded. So try to have a unique package name for the configuration resource in your common jar.

As you can see, you can use this method to programatically load log4j.xml depending on condition too.

```
package mycompany.server.listener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class Log4JInitServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        org.w3c.dom.Element log4jConfigElement = parseFromInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/unique/package/name/in/common/jar/log4j.xml"););
        DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jConfigElement);
    }

    // omit the rest and implementation of parseFromInputStream method
}
```

Comment: Different approach, interesting. I kind of wanted to avoid a programmatic approach, but this might solve another irritating problem I have in my workplace with different environments and log output directories (DEV/PROD). If I create a listener and manually load the config myself I can override properties based on the value of environment variables.

Comment: At the moment, we configure a property in our weblogic server to denote which environment we are in which I can reference in the log4j file as ${env}.

Comment: Yes, I loaded my log4j according the congiguration path I set in system environment. I have looked into many approach to solve my problem, which is the same as yours, and this is the best I can do. At first, I used maven plugin to exclude all other log4.xml but it is a bit hard in some cases. Log4j does not have the functionality to deal with this problem directly.